# Calling superclass constructors in python with different arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, arguments

```
class A():
    def __init__( self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class B():
    def __init__( self, z=0):
        self.z = z  

class AB(A,B):
    def __init__( self, x, y, z=0):
        ?
```

How can I make the constructor of AB call the constructors for A and B with the proper arguments?

I've tried

```
class AB(A,B):
    def __init__( self, x, y, z=0):
        A.__init__(x,y)
        B.__init__(z)
```

but this gives me an error.

Comment: Why do you use inheritance here instead of delegation? Because the case of multiple inheritance should be handled by using `super`, which  will not work well because of different parameters in `__init__`.

Comment: @ovgolovin Because I'm an inexperienced programmer.  I don't know what delegation is.  I will try to look into it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Other answers suggested adding `self` to the first parameter.

But usually invocations of `__init__` in parent classes are made by `super`.

Consider this example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        print('__init__ is called in A')
        self.x = x


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in B')
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class AB(B, A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in AB')
        super(AB, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`AB` class contains an order in which constructors and initializators should be called:

```
>>> AB.__mro__
(<class '__main__.AB'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

See, that first `AB`'s `__init__` is invoked, then `B`'s, then `A`'s, and then `object`'s.

Let's check:

```
>>> ab = AB(1)
__init__ is called in AB
__init__ is called in B
__init__ is called in A
```

But these calls through this chain are made by `super`. When we type `super(AB, self)`, it means: find then next class after `AB` in `__mro__` chain of `self`.

Then we should invoke `super` in `B`, looking for the next class in the chain after `B`: `super(B, self)`.

It's important to use `super` and not call manually `A.__init__(self,...)`, etc., as it may lead to problems later. [Read this for more info](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful).

So, if you stick with `super`, then there is a problem. `__init__` methods in your classes expect different parameters. And you can't know for sure the order in which `super` will be invoking methods in these classes.  The order is determined by [C3 algorithm](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) at the time of class creation. In subclasses another classes may get in-between of the call chain.  So you can't have different parameters in `__init__`, as in this case you will have always to consider all inheritance chain to understand how `__init__` methods will be called.

For example, consider adding `C(A)` and `D(B)` classes and `CD` subclass of them. Then `A` will no longer be invoked after `B`, but after `C`.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in A')
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in B')
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class AB(B,A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in AB')
        super(AB, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in C')
        super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in D')
        super(D, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class CD(D,C):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in CD')
        super(CD, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ABCD(CD,AB):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__ is called in ABCD')
        super(ABCD, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)




>>> abcd = ABCD()
__init__ is called in ABCD
__init__ is called in CD
__init__ is called in D
__init__ is called in AB
__init__ is called in B
__init__ is called in C
__init__ is called in A
```

So I think it's a good idea to think about using `delegation` instead of inheritance here.

```
class AB(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        self.a = A(x,y)
        self.b = B(z)
```

So, you just create `a` and `b` instances of `A` and `B` classes inside `AB` object. And then may use them as you need through methods by referring to `self.a` and `self.b`.

To use or not delegation depends on your case which is not clear from your question. But it may be an option to consider.

Answer (score 19):

You didn't pass `self`.

```
class AB(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        A.__init__(self, x, y)
        B.__init__(self, z)
```

Note that if this inheritance hierarchy gets more complicated, you'll run into problems with constructors not executing or getting reexecuted. Look into [`super`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) (and the [problems](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) with `super`), and don't forget to inherit from `object` if you're on 2.x and your class doesn't inherit from anything else.