# Python ServerSocket running from a separate Thread

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket, python-multithreading

I want to run a Python serversocket class in a separate thread. For that I have modified this code to support python threading:

**Original file**

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print self.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.65.1", 5001
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) 
    server.serve_forever()
```

**To My file:**

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler): 

    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False

    def setup(self):
         print('{}:{} connected'.format(*self.client_address))

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print self.data

    def finish(self):
         print('{}:{} disconnected'.format(*self.client_address))

#if __name__ == "__main__":
    def run(self):
        HOST, PORT = "192.168.65.1", 5001
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
```

**I run it as a separate thread in my main file using**

```
Thread(target=MyTCPHandler().run, args=()).start()
```

**However, when I run the main python file I got this error**

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.65.1', 37997)
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

**First, Is my modification to support threading is correct?
Please, Can anybody give me a favor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing incorrect number of parameters to the Parent method here the SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.

Read about [kargs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) and [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006310/calling-superclass-constructors-in-python-with-different-arguments) and you will understand the problem. In short kargs can take variable number of arguments.

Hope it helps.
Change

```
def __init__(self):
    self._running = True
```

to

```
def __init__(self, *kargs):
    SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, *kargs)
    self._running = True
```