# python best practices - classes are very similar, but constructor is different

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have created four classes: `experiment, experiment_type1, experiment_type2 and experiment_type3`

`experiment` is an abstract class, it cannot be instantiated. It has 2 methods, `__init__(self)` and `run(self)` where `run(self)` is abstract.

`experiment_type1` and `experiment_type2` are derived from experiment. They inherit the `__init__(self)` from `experiment` (so they share the same constructor) but they implement `run(self)` differently from each other.

My problem is with `experiment_type3` class. It also only has the `run(self)` method, implemented differently from `experiment_type1` and `experiment_type2`, but its constructor takes an additional argument. Its constructor is of the form `__init__(self, parameter)`

Ideally I would like `experiment_type3` to be derived from `experiment`. But there is a constructor mismatch. What is the best way to handle this? Programming in python in this case.

**Edit:**
This is the code for experiment and experiment_type3. As you can see it depends on self.epsilon which does not exist.

import numpy as np
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from Bandit import Bandit

```
class experiment(ABC):
    def __init__(self, num_iter, bandit_list): #epsilon is the chance to explore, num_iter is num of iterations, bandit_list is the list of the bandits
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.bandit_list = bandit_list
        self.best_bandit = np.random.choice(len(bandit_list))

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('derived class must implement run() method!')

class eg_experiment(experiment):
    def run(self):
        for iteration in range(self.num_iter):
            bandit = np.random.choice(len(self.bandit_list))
            if(np.random.random() > self.epsilon):
                bandit = self.best_bandit
            self.bandit_list[self.best_bandit].pull()
            self.best_bandit = np.argmax([bandit.current_mean for bandit in self.bandit_list])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Inherit the superclass \_\_init\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535832/python-inherit-the-superclass-init)

Comment: You should include the unabridged source with your post it's much more likely to get a good response.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006310/489590 I think it's related.

Comment: Override the constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best solution. It is possible but all I want to do is add a self.parameter = parameter. Not sure that warrants code duplication of the entire constructor

Comment: Then call the super class constructor in the overridden constructor and then set your attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments point out, using `super()` on the parent class's `__init__` should give you what you want.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, parameter)
        self.parameter = parameter

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, parameter, new_parameter)
        super().__init__(parameter)
        self.new_parameter = parameter
```

or in your case

```
class eg_experiment(experiment):
    def __init__(num_iter, bandit_list, epsilon):
        super().__init__(num_iter, bandit_list)  #Python3
        # super(experiment,self).__init__(num_iter, bandit_list) # Pythyon2.7
        self.epsilon = epsilon
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a saying: "If your class only has two methods, and one is `__init__`, use a function instead." Especially here, where there is no common implementation of the `run` method. You just have a bunch of independent functions with similar signatures.

```
def run_experiment_one(num_iter, bandit_list):
    ...

def run_experiment_two(num_iter, bandit_list):
    ...

def run_experiment_three(num_iter, bandit_list, epislon):
    ...
```