# Python 2.7: How can a class created inside another one query a variable of the class creating it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this is wrong, but I don't know why, not how to do it right. I don't want myParent to be myChlid's superclass. I can't really find words to ask what I want to do so I didn't find any way to find an answer online. Maybe you can answer it :)

```
class myParent():
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.child = myChild(parent_ = self)
        self.myVar = whatever

class myChild():
    def __init__(self, parent_):
        self.parent_ = parent_
        print self.parent_.myVar

myParent(whatever)
```

It raises this error :

`# AttributeError: myParent instance has no attribute 'myVar' #`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006310/calling-superclass-constructors-in-python-with-different-arguments

Comment: Looks fine, except that you need to set the member before you can read it. That's just a sequence-of-events problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `myVar` from within `myChild.__init__` because you're creating the myChild instance before you create the `self.myVar` attribute. Try switching the order of those lines.

```
class myParent():
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.myVar = whatever
        self.child = myChild(parent_ = self)
```